# creating channels / custome fields via a module

Tags: custom-fields, multiple-channels

I've been asked to create a competition module for EE.
I think that it'd be best to have the module create a new channel and custom fields. I can create my own tables and have a nice separate area, but I think it'd be better to have the user simply go to: create channel competition.. etc..

Is this possible from a module?
I can't find any info on 'automating' channel creation..

Sorry if this is a dumb Q.. I've not used EE in a while..

Tris..

Comment: Thought.. can I just create my own forms etc, but add a link to my module in the 'publish' menu.. that'll do. No need to worry about custom channels and custom fields etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have found a solution that won't require it, but to answer your original question, it is possible for third-party add-ons to build Channel structures, using the [Channel APIs](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/index.html#id2).

Comment: Ah, that's cool. I can't see how to set up Custom fields that way, only edit existing ones. shame, it's so nearly what I want. I'll continue to investigate the 'add an item to the publish menu' idea.. Cheers though, very useful to know!

Comment: OMG I just REALLY read the docs and it DOES seem to do what I want.. amazing.. I feel so blonde right now..